# Convert a single-character string to its codepoint

Tags: elixir

I know I can get the codepoint of a character using the `?a` syntax.

```
iex> ?a
97
```

But what about when `a` is a binary, `"a"`? How can I get the codepoint in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use binary pattern matching:

```elixir
iex(1)> <<codepoint::utf8>> = "a"
"a"
iex(2)> codepoint
97
```

Or use [`String.to_charlist/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_charlist/1), and extract the first value:

```elixir
iex> "a" |> String.to_charlist |> hd
97
```

Answer (score 5):

Beware of UTF-8 decomposed form. It’s always safer to call [`String.normalize/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#normalize/2) on input before further processing (passing `:nfc` as a second argument.)

One might expect

```
<<cp::utf8>> = "á"
```

to work, but it raises, while

```
<<cp::utf8>> = "á"
```

works pretty fine. There is no typo above, **`"á"`** in the first example and **`"á"`** in the second example are different.

```
"á" == "á"
#⇒ false
```

To safely match both composed and decomposed, no matter what, one might explicitly normalize it to *composed* form upfront.

```
with <<cp::utf8>> <- String.normalize("á", :nfc),
  do: cp
#⇒ 225
```

---

All the examples above are copy-pasteable.

```
"á"
|> String.normalize(:nfc)
|> String.to_charlist()
|> hd()
#⇒ 225
```

but

```
"á"
|> String.to_charlist()
|> hd()
#⇒ 97
```

Comment: I think your strings got normalized because both the `á`s are equivalent when I copy and paste. I can reproduce if I do `"a\u0301"` though.

Comment: I had it triple-checked. Your terminal might do normalize on paste, maybe.

Comment: Seems like some sort of black magic is going on. Even TextEdit normalises it. I managed to test it by saving this page's HTML and editing it into an elixir script. Interestingly, `?á` is vulnerable to the same problem: `** (SyntaxError) unicode.exs:1: unexpected token: "́" (column 11, codepoint U+0301)`

Comment: LOL MacOS is so MacOS. `?́ #⇒ 769` in my Linux box works in any terminal without any issue. That’s exactly why I always advocate against using MacOS for development. `?á` with _decomposed acute_ would not work because `?` grabs the only symbol and does not make any normalization. `?á #⇒ 225` works pretty fine (composed `"á"`.)